# Jquery change iside div width size, based on outside div size

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i would like to change the value of a div width, based on the outside div width

I am new in jquery and javascript and tried this code:

```
if ($('col-md-4 col-sm-6').width() <= 320 ){
   $('.card-info').width(120px)
};
```

but it didn't work...

the html is:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
 <div class="card-info">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
 <div class="card-info">
 </div>
</div>
(...)
```

Could some one help me to find out how to do that, change div "card-info" to 120px width if the div "col-md-4 col-sm6" is 320px or less.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Without CSS is not easy to understand. You have some typos in your jQuery. It should be  $('.col-md-4.col-sm-6')  and  .width(120)

Comment: For starters the selectors are invalid in the `if()`. A few minutes reading through the selectors api would help http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not selecting the col-md-4 and col-sm-6 class in jQuery. You missed the dot(.) before `$('col-md-4 col-sm-6')` `col-md-4` here and then a comma(,) and the another dot before `col-sm-6`.
The solution would be

```
    if ($('.col-md-4, .col-sm-6').width() <= 320 ) {
      $('.card-info').width(120); 
    }
```

or

```
        if ($('.col-md-4, .col-sm-6').width() <= 320 ) {
          $('.card-info').css('width', '120px'); 
        }
```